# pyparsing: is it possible to add lineno/col (or startloc/endloc) to all tokens?

Tags: python, pyparsing

Are needed for a better error reporting after parsing the schema i.e.

```
enum MyEnum {
  Key1,
  Key2,
  Key3
}

table Test {
  field1: MyEnum = MyEnum.Key1;
  field2: MyEnum = MyEnum.WrongKey;
}
```

I want to report that `MyEnum.WrongKey` is not found but I also want to pint the location (line & col)
Here https://github.com/bog-dan-ro/flatbuffers/blob/pyfbsc/bin/fbsc.py is the full parser srcs

Answer (score 1):

You could try to define your parser, so that `MyEnum.WrongKey` does not parse. Then you print out where the parsing fails with:

```
try:
    your_parser.parseString(your_schema)
except ParseException as pe:
   print(pe)
   print("at column: {}".format(pe.col))
```

See the [documentation for `ParseException`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParseException-class.html).

Comment: Sadly I need to do it after the parsing is done, because the script might include other scripts and I didn't found a way to parse those while parsing the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap any expression using pyparsing's `locatedExpr` helper. From the online docs (https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#locatedExpr):

Example:

```
wd = Word(alphas)
for match in locatedExpr(wd).searchString("ljsdf123lksdjjf123lkkjj1222"):
    print(match)
```

prints:

```
[[0, 'ljsdf', 5]]
[[8, 'lksdjjf', 15]]
[[18, 'lkkjj', 23]]
```